# How do I test if my modem/router device is acting as a pure modem?

Tags: modem

So I called UPC to disable this wi-free thing(free wifi from my network to anyone who uses UPC and wants to connect to it and I can only disable it calling UPC) they forgot to mention when they swapped my modem and they did and I also told them I'd like all routing to be disabled on my modem and have my own router handle it.

Now the customer service agent told me it's done but I'd like to test it if I can. I'm pretty suspicious because I can connect to the internet using any of the modem's 4 ports. So it's at least acting like a switch right?

I also set the modem to bridge mode(this should disable routing right?) but that didn't disable the wi-free so I had to call them for it. Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions I'm kinda noob. Thanks

Comment: I'd say 4 functioning sockets is enough of a giveaway; if each device connected gets its own IP Address, that's your second clue. 3rd is that your own router gets a private IP, not a public one. Type 'what's my IP address' into Google & if it's not the same as your own router thinks it is, then that's your confirmation. [BTW, I've no idea who UPC are & why they would not allow a customer access to a config page at the router's internal IP address to set that up for yourself]

Comment: @Tetsujin  you write so ambiguously, you write "I'd say 4 functioning sockets is enough of a giveaway;"    A dead giveaway for what? For it being a "pure modem" or for it being a router?   And functioning how.  You write  "If each device connected gets its own IP Address, that's your second clue."    again what are you talking about, a public IP address or a private IP address. (Continued)

Comment: @Tetsujin  (cont) And anyhow, either way the "4 ports"  don't get an IP whether it's a modem or a home router, they don't, it's the device's connected to them that might. And you still have to specify whether public or private.   You write "our own router gets a private IP, not a public one"  Well, i've heard of managed switches, and routers running DDWRT in bridge modem having an IP to manage them which I guess might be different to their public one, and might be private.(Continued)

Comment: @Tetsujin (cont) And I have heard of somebody plugging multiple computers into a switch, their ISP gave them 5 IPs.. And it wasn't an expensive service either. Quite a slow speed, just a regular ISP.  And I heard that each device got its own public IP.. That makes sense. So if that's indeed possible, and i'm sure it is, then you can get "4 functioning ports" each with an IP, whether it's a router or whether it's bridged. So I don't think what you write is correct there either.

Comment: @barlop - by the time you'd finished writing your scathing dissertation on my comment, you could have posted an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the device to bridge mode should disable NAT and provide what you want in that respect. When that is correctly setup, usually you can only use one, specific port and the device's wifi will stop working. (Though the free wifi might continue to work.)

To determine if the free wifi bit has been disabled, use a wifi-capable device to see what hot spots are available. (Usually these devices have a way of selecting which hot spot you want to connect to.) With the free wifi, there would be your personal hot spot as well as a hot spot for the free wifi service, usually with a well known name. Without free wifi, only your own hot spot should be visible.